# How to call a function with struct as input?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, struct

Here is my struct definition, function and the portion calling the function.

```
public struct NewSigningRequest
{
    public string SerialNumber;
    //public string Requestor;
    public string Sponsor;
    public string Approver;
    public string BusinessJustification;
    public byte[] DebugFile;
    public string DebugFileName;
    public string FirmwareVersion;
    public string FirmwareDescription;
    public byte[] SmokeTestResult;
    public string ProductName;
    public string SigningType;
}
    static public bool CreateSigningRequest(NewSigningRequest Request)
    {
        Request = new NewSigningRequest();
        bool succeeded = false;
        string sqlcmdString = sqlQueryNewSigningRequest;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand Insertcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, con);

        SqlParameter SerialNumber = new SqlParameter("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        SerialNumber.Value = Request.SerialNumber;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(SerialNumber);

        SqlParameter Requestor = new SqlParameter("@Requestor", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        Requestor.Value = GetRequestor.GetRequestorAlias();
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(Requestor);

        SqlParameter Sponsor = new SqlParameter("@Sponsor", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        Sponsor.Value = Request.Sponsor;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(Sponsor);

        SqlParameter BusinessJustification = new SqlParameter("@BusinessJustification", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2000);
        BusinessJustification.Value = Request.BusinessJustification;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(BusinessJustification);

        SqlParameter DebugFile = new SqlParameter("@DebugFile", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000);
        DebugFile.Value = Request.DebugFile;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(DebugFile);

        SqlParameter DebugFileName = new SqlParameter("@DebugFileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        DebugFileName.Value = Request.DebugFileName;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(DebugFileName);

        SqlParameter ProductName = new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        ProductName.Value = Request.ProductName;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(ProductName);

        SqlParameter SigningType = new SqlParameter("@SigningType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
        SigningType.Value = Request.SigningType;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(SigningType);

        SqlParameter FirmwareVersion = new SqlParameter("@FirmwareVersion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        FirmwareVersion.Value = Request.FirmwareVersion;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(FirmwareVersion);

        SqlParameter FirmwareDescription = new SqlParameter("@FirmwareDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250);
        FirmwareDescription.Value = Request.FirmwareDescription;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(FirmwareDescription);

        SqlParameter SmokeTestResult = new SqlParameter("@SmokeTestResult", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000);
        SmokeTestResult.Value = Request.SmokeTestResult;
        Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(SmokeTestResult);

        return succeeded;
    }
```

this is how I am trying to call it

```
                NewSigningRequest Request;
                byte[] bin;
                string FileName;
                if (FileUpload.HasFile)
                {
                    bin = new byte[FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                    HttpPostedFile mybin = FileUpload.PostedFile;
                    FileName = mybin.FileName;
                    mybin.InputStream.Read(bin, 0, FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    bin = null;
                    FileName = "";
                }
                string NameAlias = @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                int index = NameAlias.IndexOf("\\") + 1;
                string sAlias = NameAlias.Substring(index);

                byte[] SmokeTest;

                if (FileUploadSTR.HasFile)
                {
                    SmokeTest = new byte[FileUploadSTR.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                    HttpPostedFile mySmokeTest = FileUploadSTR.PostedFile;
                    mySmokeTest.InputStream.Read(SmokeTest, 0, FileUploadSTR.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    SmokeTest = null;
                }
                Request.SerialNumber = TextBoxSerialNumber.Text;
                Request.Sponsor = TextBoxSponsor.Text;
                Request.BusinessJustification = TextBoxBJ.Text;
                if (bin == null)
                {
                    Request.DebugFile = new byte[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    Request.DebugFile = bin;
                }
                Request.DebugFileName = FileName;
                Request.FirmwareVersion = TextBoxFV.Text;
                Request.FirmwareDescription = TextBoxFD.Text;
                if (TextBoxSigningType.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    Request.SigningType = drp2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Request.SigningType = TextBoxSigningType.Text.ToUpper();
                }
                if (SmokeTest == null)
                {
                    Request.SmokeTestResult = new byte[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    Request.SmokeTestResult = SmokeTest;
                }
                SurfaceSignDBAccess.CreateSigningRequest(Request);
```

upon calling this function, gives error saying that "use of unassigned local variable 'Request'."

What should be the right way to call this function?

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Is there a specific line which throws the error?

Comment: yeah the last line SurfaceSignDBAccess.CreateSigningRequest(Request);

Comment: `            SqlParameter SerialNumber = new SqlParameter("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            SerialNumber.Value = Request.SerialNumber;
            Insertcmd.Parameters.Add(SerialNumber);
`code above is in the function and the below code is assigning values to the input struct of a function before calling it`                    Request.SerialNumber = TextBoxSerialNumber.Text;
`but the value is not assigned at all.

Answer (score 0):

NewSigningRequest Request; - is never initialized in the method, before calling 
        SurfaceSignDBAccess.CreateSigningRequest(Request);

try this:
var request = new NewSigningRequest();// in the first line of code of the second code snippet.
And in the static method, remove the following code. 
        Request = new NewSigningRequest();

Comment: `var request = new NewSigningRequest();` - not needed for a value type.

Comment: I made the changes but now got error saying that sql parameter are not allocated with the values. is this the right way to give values to the struct variables and pass to a fuction